# Получение себестоимости товара через API МоегоСклада

Tags: мойсклад-api, moysklad-json-api

Как можно получить себестоимость товара на заданную дату?
При запросе:

```
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/stock/all?stockMode=all&product.id=291fb2ac-2e36-11e6-7a69-9711000b4b5e&filter=moment=2018-08-31%2016:31
```

параметр момент никак не влияет на результат.

Answer (score 2):

`filter=` лишний, и формат даты смотрите в [документации](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-get) (идем по ссылке и кликаем на показать, чтоб раскрыть иформацию по параметрам)

В вашем случае попробуйте:

```
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/stock/all?stockMode=all&product.id=291fb2ac-2e36-11e6-7a69-9711000b4b5e&moment=2018-08-31%2016-31-00
```